# Как правильно создать глобальные переменные в файле .h

Tags: c++

Есть проект, в котором несколько десятков файлов .cpp, все они должны иметь доступ к глобальным переменным  WinAPI, под которые я выделил отдельный заголовочный файл globalvariable.h
В какой то момент, получается, переменные дублируются и выдается сообщение об ошибке на уровне .obj
Как указать компилятору чтоб он использовал эти переменные в файле globalvariable.h, а не создавал их заново вставляя в код? как правильно создавать глобальные переменные, чтоб они были видны из всех файлов реализации .cpp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильный способ такой. Создайте все нужные переменные, но поместите их в cpp файл. А в h файле объявите с `extern`. Все. Теперь просто добавляйте этот h файл всем нужным файлам. А ещё хорошо их завернуть в namespace.

header

```
namespace global {
  extern int data;
}
```

cpp

```
namespace global {
  int data = 0;
}
```

в нужном месте теперь обращайтесь как `global::data`.

И не забудьте добавить cpp файл в компиляцию и потом в линковку.

Второй способ - это создать себе класс-синглтон, который и будет хранить все эти глобальные переменные. В некоторых случаях это может быть заметно лучше.

Третий способ - без глобальных переменных. И не будет проблем.